# What is the Debian equivalent of urw-fonts (needed for utf-8 in wkhtmltopdf)?

Tags: utf-8, fonts, debian, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert an html document with text in multiple languages (utf-8 encoding) to pdf using wkhtmltopdf, and ran into the exact issue described here:

[Squared characters issue on wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627802/squared-characters-issue-on-wkhtmltopdf)

The most popular answers there are to install urw-fonts, which seems to have worked for many people with this issue. But when I search for this package in the Debian apt repository, it doesn't find anything. Someone suggested installing gsfonts-x11, but that didn't fix the issue.

**My question is:**

Is there a similar/equivalent Debian font package that can be used by wkhtmltopdf to correctly render utf-8 fonts?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find anything? I'm having this problem too.

Comment: @RossTheBoss nope, had to use a workaround by creating an image of the multi-language text and putting that into the document (just saw this comment)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting other languages rendering in wkhtmltopdf:

1. created a folder: /path/to/downloaded/fonts
2. create fonts.conf (see below)

```
/path/to/downloaded/fonts/fonts.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/path/to/downloaded/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

3. downloaded Google's Noto fonts into /var/task/fonts. For each language you need, you can download its associated language ttf files.
4. Set your ENV variables:
   `FONT_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/downloaded/fonts/` and `FONTCONFIG_FILE=/path/to/downloaded/fonts/fonts.conf`
5. In the target HTML file, set the meta tag in the head of the document:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

You may find that you need to add additional fonts, but they are found on the the
[Google Noto Site](https://www.google.com/get/noto/). I used all the *-regular.ttf files to keep my container smaller.

If you happen to be doing this in AWS / amazonlinux2, you also need to set:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/wkhtmltopdf;`
You can confirm that the libaries are mapped correctly with:
`ldd /path/to/wkhtmltopdf`
Your result should look like this:

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc7f5cf000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /var/task/lib/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f1ea6db1000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /var/task/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f1ea6b74000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /var/task/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f1ea68d0000)
        libXext.so.6 => /var/task/lib/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1ea66be000)
        libX11.so.6 => /var/task/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f1ea6380000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1ea616b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1ea5f67000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1ea5d5f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1ea5b41000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1ea57bf000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1ea547f000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1ea5269000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1ea4ebe000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1ea6fbb000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /var/task/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f1ea4c8c000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /var/task/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f1ea4a64000)
        libXau.so.6 => /var/task/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1ea4860000)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce59b0000)
```

If the path is wrong, it'll look like this:

```
        libXrender.so.1 => not found
        libfontconfig.so.1 => not found
        libfreetype.so.6 => not found
        libXext.so.6 => not found
        libX11.so.6 => not found
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2f1fed9000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2f1fcd5000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2f1facd000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2f1f8af000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2f1f52d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2f1f1ed000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2f1efd7000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2f1ec2c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2f200ee000)
```