# Rupee symbol shows as blank box on invoice report in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, wkhtmltopdf, centos6

**Issue summary :** Rupee symbol shows up as box on invoice report. It shows up correctly on the web but when a report is printed then it shows a box instead of the rupee symbol.

**What I have tried :**

- Checked default currency for the company; it is INR.
- The INR symbol is showing correct in the INR currency i.e. ₹
- Downgraded wkhtmltopdf from version 0.12.2 to 0.12.1 as the former has caused problem to many people.
- Even installed a font called **Foradian Rupee Font**
- I have Checked by changing default currency to Euro and the euro symbol is showing up on the prints.
- Tried everything that is given here but nothing helped: [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627802/squared-characters-issue-on-wkhtmltopdf)

So, I have tried a lot of things but nothing worked. If anyone here knows what is happening and could help me move to the right direction, it would be really helpful.

Comment: downgrade wkhtmltopdf to the version 0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Rupee symbol isn't in the font that is used in the report. Try changing the font of your report by adding custom css? eg:

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```